# footer query data from db show in master.blade laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, frontend

I need to query information form database `[company name ,company address]`
and my code can show 1 page

my controller

```
public function index()
{
    $footer = DB::table('pjt_setting')->pluck('value','setting_name')->toArray();
    //dd($footer);
    return view('frontend.index',compact('footer'));
}
```

Master blade

```
<!-- topbar -->
@include('frontend.layouts.topbar')
<!-- top -->
@include('frontend.layouts.nav')
<!-- header slide -->
<!-- Main content -->
    @yield('content')
<!-- /.content -->
<footer class="footer-distributed">
    @include('frontend.layouts.footer')
</footer>
```

Footer blade

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="footer-left">
        <h3>{{ $footer["companyname"]}}</h3>
        <p class="footer-company-name">Phuket Jet Tour &copy; 2018</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer-center"></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="footer-right">
        <div class="companyaddress">
            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
            <p>{{ $footer["companyaddress"] }}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
            <p>{{ $footer["phone"] }}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
            <p><a href="mailto:{{ $footer["email"] }}">{{ $footer["email"] }}</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Index page no problem but, I link to contact page 
show error `"Undefined variable:footer"`.
How I can edit

Comment: show your controller code for contact page

Comment: public function index() {
        return view('frontend.contact-us');
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `$footer` in your `contact` view:

```
$footer = DB::table('pjt_setting')->pluck('value','setting_name')->toArray();
return view('frontend.contact-us',compact('footer'));
```

Best way would be to `share` this `footer` from `base controller` for every `view`

```
class BaseController extends \Controller
{

   protected $footer;

   public function __construct() 
   {
       $this->footer = DB::table('pjt_setting')->pluck('value','setting_name')->toArray();
       View::share('footer', $footer);
   }

}
```

Comment: thank you so much , i don't know trait you have document online ?

Comment: trait won't help here but you can see its official doc

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as said by @Sohel0415

Or you can do this using Trait.

Comment: you mean https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/notifications#using-the-notifiable-trait right?

Comment: No, using php trait functionality

Comment: Check -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657629/how-to-use-traits-laravel-5-2 and http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php