# Laravel: Check condition on a column before save it in database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using a script that has a insert query like this:

```
DB::table('documents')->insert('amount' => $amount, <some other columns>);
```

this query used over and over (more than 200) in some controllers.

Now I want to  add a condition that if the value that assigned to 'amount' is 0 the insertion query be ignored.

A simple (but BAD) way is adding condition to all where insertion called. 
A better way is I define a function (in a library or something like that) and take query in it and change all controllers that currently insertion query is in there. But as I said before it is time-consuming.

Is there a better way (like accessor/mutator or something like to check a condition before executing this query?

Comment: you can define a trait write logic over their and use in your controller file before inserting record

Comment: Use trait step to implement trait https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657629/how-to-use-traits-laravel-5-2

Comment: @PrashantPrajapati Defining Trait is like the second way I say in 2nd way (in a library or something like that).

Comment: if you go for accessor/ mutator you have to define the same logic again & again in each model where else in trait only 1 time logic to be written

Answer (score 0):

If you have the amounts in an array or collection, walk through that and filter those elements where the amount is 0. Than perform a mass insert.

If possible, please try to avoid the usage of `DB`, instead use the Model’s static create method.